# lua nested tables insert table into another table

Tags: lua, nested, lua-table

ok i have this table :

```
 tbm.offsets = { -- facedir indexed (+1)
    { -- facedir = 0
        { -- first line
            { X = -1, Y =  2, Z =  1 },
            { X =  0, Y =  2, Z =  1 },
            { X =  1, Y =  2, Z =  1 }
        },
        { -- second line
            { X = -1, Y =  1, Z =  1 },
            { X =  0, Y =  1, Z =  1 },
            { X =  1, Y =  1, Z =  1 }
        },
        { -- third line
            { X = -1, Y =  0, Z =  1 },
            { X =  0, Y =  0, Z =  1 },
            { X =  1, Y =  0, Z =  1 }
        },
        { -- forth line
            { X = -1, Y = -1, Z =  1 },
            { X =  0, Y = -1, Z =  1 },
            { X =  1, Y = -1, Z =  1 }
        }
    },
    { -- facedir = 1
        { -- first line
            { X =  1, Y =  2, Z = -1 },
            { X =  1, Y =  2, Z =  0 },
            { X =  1, Y =  2, Z =  1 }
        },
        { -- second line
            { X =  1, Y =  1, Z = -1 },
            { X =  1, Y =  1, Z =  0 },
            { X =  1, Y =  1, Z =  1 }
        },
        { -- third line
            { X =  1, Y =  0, Z = -1 },
            { X =  1, Y =  0, Z =  0 },
            { X =  1, Y =  0, Z =  1 }
        },
        { -- forth line
            { X =  1, Y = -1, Z = -1 },
            { X =  1, Y = -1, Z =  0 },
            { X =  1, Y = -1, Z =  1 }
        }
    },
    { -- facedir = 2
        { -- first line
            { X = -1, Y =  2, Z = -1 },
            { X =  0, Y =  2, Z = -1 },
            { X =  1, Y =  2, Z = -1 }
        },
        { -- second line
            { X = -1, Y =  1, Z = -1 },
            { X =  0, Y =  1, Z = -1 },
            { X =  1, Y =  1, Z = -1 }
        },
        { -- third line
            { X = -1, Y =  0, Z = -1 },
            { X =  0, Y =  0, Z = -1 },
            { X =  1, Y =  0, Z = -1 }
        },
        { -- forth line
            { X = -1, Y = -1, Z = -1 },
            { X =  0, Y = -1, Z = -1 },
            { X =  1, Y = -1, Z = -1 }
        }
    },
    { -- facedir = 3
        { -- first line
            { X = -1, Y =  2, Z = -1 },
            { X = -1, Y =  2, Z =  0 },
            { X = -1, Y =  2, Z =  1 }
        },
        { -- second line
            { X = -1, Y =  1, Z = -1 },
            { X = -1, Y =  1, Z =  0 },
            { X = -1, Y =  1, Z =  1 }
        },
        { -- third line
            { X = -1, Y =  0, Z = -1 },
            { X = -1, Y =  0, Z =  0 },
            { X = -1, Y =  0, Z =  1 }
        },
        { -- forth line
            { X = -1, Y = -1, Z = -1 },
            { X = -1, Y = -1, Z =  0 },
            { X = -1, Y = -1, Z =  1 }
        }
    }
}
```

it is a static table in Lua already but i want to make it dynamic, the table lists XYZ cordinates for a number of lines of blocks, i want to be able to adjust the coordinates table based on user input, for example if they want a grid of 20 blocks 3 lines high how would i assemble the table from within a for loop? each block has an xyz and is in a row, each row is part of a block and the coordinates depend on which way the direction is facing.

what i have begun to figure out in the last 15 mins it would look something like:

```
    temp = {}
    temp1 = {}
    temp2 = {}
    temp3 = {}

  for facedir = 1, 4 do
   for block = 1, 5 do 
    for Line = 1,5 do
      for X1 = -5, 5 do
       for Y1 = 5,-1 do 
         for Z1 = 1, 5 do
            temp = {X = X1, Y = Y1, Z = Z1}
          end
        end
      end
       temp1{ line = temp }
    end
     temp2{block = temp1}
   end
     temp3{facedir = temp2}
  end
```

would the above code work? or what is a better/easy solution to implement, this code will be executed repeatedly, sometimes with he same variables sometimes with different variables.

Static Sample Table Formated with lua print script in console"

```
1 table: 0x95efdc8
    1 table: 0x95efe18
        1 table: 0x95f1050
            X - -1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        2 table: 0x95f10d0
            X - 0
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        3 table: 0x95efb28
            X - 1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
    2 table: 0x95efba8
        1 table: 0x95efbf0
            X - -1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        2 table: 0x95f1658
            X - 0
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        3 table: 0x95f16d8
            X - 1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
    3 table: 0x95f1758
        1 table: 0x95f1780
            X - -1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        2 table: 0x95f1800
            X - 0
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        3 table: 0x95f1880
            X - 1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
    4 table: 0x95f1900
        1 table: 0x95f1948
            X - -1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
        2 table: 0x95f19c8
            X - 0
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
        3 table: 0x95f1a48
            X - 1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
2 table: 0x95f1ac8
    1 table: 0x95f1b18
        1 table: 0x95f1b60
            X - 1
            Y - 2
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f2308
            X - 1
            Y - 2
            Z - 0
        3 table: 0x95f2388
            X - 1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
    2 table: 0x95f2408
        1 table: 0x95f2430
            X - 1
            Y - 1
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f24b0
            X - 1
            Y - 1
            Z - 0
        3 table: 0x95f2530
            X - 1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
    3 table: 0x95f25b0
        1 table: 0x95f25f8
            X - 1
            Y - 0
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f2678
            X - 1
            Y - 0
            Z - 0
        3 table: 0x95f26f8
            X - 1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
    4 table: 0x95f2778
        1 table: 0x95f27c0
            X - 1
            Y - -1
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f2840
            X - 1
            Y - -1
            Z - 0
        3 table: 0x95f28c0
            X - 1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
3 table: 0x95f2940
    1 table: 0x95f2990
        1 table: 0x95f29d8
            X - -1
            Y - 2
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f2a58
            X - 0
            Y - 2
            Z - -1
        3 table: 0x95f2ad8
            X - 1
            Y - 2
            Z - -1
    2 table: 0x95f2b58
        1 table: 0x95f2ba0
            X - -1
            Y - 1
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f2c20
            X - 0
            Y - 1
            Z - -1
        3 table: 0x95f2ca0
            X - 1
            Y - 1
            Z - -1
    3 table: 0x95f2d20
        1 table: 0x95f2d68
            X - -1
            Y - 0
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f2de8
            X - 0
            Y - 0
            Z - -1
        3 table: 0x95f2e68
            X - 1
            Y - 0
            Z - -1
    4 table: 0x95f2ee8
        1 table: 0x95f2f30
            X - -1
            Y - -1
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f2fb0
            X - 0
            Y - -1
            Z - -1
        3 table: 0x95f3030
            X - 1
            Y - -1
            Z - -1
4 table: 0x95f30b0
    1 table: 0x95f3100
        1 table: 0x95f3148
            X - -1
            Y - 2
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f31c8
            X - -1
            Y - 2
            Z - 0
        3 table: 0x95f3248
            X - -1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
    2 table: 0x95f32c8
        1 table: 0x95f3310
            X - -1
            Y - 1
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f3390
            X - -1
            Y - 1
            Z - 0
        3 table: 0x95f3410
            X - -1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
    3 table: 0x95f3490
        1 table: 0x95f34d8
            X - -1
            Y - 0
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f3558
            X - -1
            Y - 0
            Z - 0
        3 table: 0x95f35d8
            X - -1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
    4 table: 0x95f3658
        1 table: 0x95f36a0
            X - -1
            Y - -1
            Z - -1
        2 table: 0x95f3720
            X - -1
            Y - -1
            Z - 0
        3 table: 0x95f37a0
            X - -1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
```

output from current script:

```
1 table: 0x95f3848
    1 table: 0x95f3870
        1 table: 0x95f3898
            X - -1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        2 table: 0x95f3918
            X - -1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        3 table: 0x95f3998
            X - -1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        4 table: 0x95f3a40
            X - -1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
        5 table: 0x95f3ac0
            X - 0
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        6 table: 0x95f3a18
            X - 0
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        7 table: 0x95f3be0
            X - 0
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        8 table: 0x95f3c60
            X - 0
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
        9 table: 0x95f3ce0
            X - 1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        10 table: 0x95f3b40
            X - 1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        11 table: 0x95f3e40
            X - 1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        12 table: 0x95f3ec0
            X - 1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
    2 table: 0x95f3f40
        1 table: 0x95f3f68
            X - -1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        2 table: 0x95f3fe8
            X - -1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        3 table: 0x95f4068
            X - -1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        4 table: 0x95f4110
            X - -1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
        5 table: 0x95f4190
            X - 0
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        6 table: 0x95f40e8
            X - 0
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        7 table: 0x95f42b0
            X - 0
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        8 table: 0x95f4330
            X - 0
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
        9 table: 0x95f43b0
            X - 1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        10 table: 0x95f4210
            X - 1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        11 table: 0x95eff98
            X - 1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        12 table: 0x95f4568
            X - 1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
2 table: 0x95f45e8
    1 table: 0x95f4610
        1 table: 0x95f4638
            X - -1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        2 table: 0x95f46b8
            X - -1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        3 table: 0x95f4738
            X - -1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        4 table: 0x95f47e0
            X - -1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
        5 table: 0x95f4860
            X - 0
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        6 table: 0x95f47b8
            X - 0
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        7 table: 0x95f4980
            X - 0
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        8 table: 0x95f4a00
            X - 0
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
        9 table: 0x95f4a80
            X - 1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        10 table: 0x95f48e0
            X - 1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        11 table: 0x95f4be0
            X - 1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        12 table: 0x95efa88
            X - 1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
    2 table: 0x95efcf0
        1 table: 0x95efe98
            X - -1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        2 table: 0x95f0528
            X - -1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        3 table: 0x95f0ec8
            X - -1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        4 table: 0x95f1c28
            X - -1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
        5 table: 0x95f1ca8
            X - 0
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        6 table: 0x95f1c00
            X - 0
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        7 table: 0x95f1dc8
            X - 0
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        8 table: 0x95f0788
            X - 0
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
        9 table: 0x95f0808
            X - 1
            Y - 2
            Z - 1
        10 table: 0x95f1df0
            X - 1
            Y - 1
            Z - 1
        11 table: 0x95f0968
            X - 1
            Y - 0
            Z - 1
        12 table: 0x95f09e8
            X - 1
            Y - -1
            Z - 1
```

in the output from the script there is 12 entries, and there should only be 3, so im playing with it...

Comment: Your for loops should work as they have the correct syntax (http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html). However, your temp, temp1, temp2 and temp3 will also be nil as they are outside the loops that define them. Remember this is lua so you can always open the lua interpreter and experiment with this stuff on the command line!

Comment: if i could find a stupid lua interpreter that i can install on debian that would give me something to play with i would, i am really good with php and lua doesnt seem that different except this table thing, i have never seen a data structure that is so , well unstructured...lol. since the temp is outside the loop that defines them that would be like, they are local variables instead of global? and then based on that couldnt i just declare them on the outside or withing the funtion? or do they have to be declared in the loop? this routine will be in a function, i dont know what or if that helps

Comment: `apt-get install lua5.1` or `apt-get install lua5.2`.

Comment: `temp1{}` is a function call not table creation by the way.

Comment: That `will be nil` comment from @Stratus3D is not exactly correct either. Given the code above (modified to be `temp = {}`, etc.) the loops will be constantly overwriting the temp, temp1, etc. variables with new tables and at no point will any of them be nil. If you intended to append entries to each table then you need to do that instead of simple assignment.

Comment: @Etan Reisner so if i amend the temp array variables as i have done above and called the routine and used the data i could build a table like the one i have put as the sample or it will only be filled over each time the loop runs? i am trying to concatenate all of the data into a single table as referenced as 'facedir'

also i have that LUA package on this box, no IDE that i found and i dont wanna have to keep pluggin the terminal every time i make a minor change. terminal is a major pita for development purposes, great for diagnostic but crappy otherwise.

Comment: The php cli isn't an ide either. There are IDEs (and IDE-like editors) that can be used with lua if you want to do that. Personally I don't. If you modify every `tempX{...}` and `tempX = {...}` instance to be appends to the `tempX` table instead and put that all in a function then yes, you should be able to use code very much like that to create a table similar to what you started with. (I haven't evaluated the actual flow and data to determine if you get the exact results you expect but that should be simple enough to test.)

Comment: You will need to reset each nested table in the appropriate outer loops to get the results you want as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified to be syntactically and logically correct the above code looks like this:

```
local temp3 = {}

for facedir = 1, 4 do
    local temp2 = {}

    for block = 1, 5 do
        local temp1 = {}

        for Line = 1,5 do
            local temp = {}

            for X1 = -5, 5 do
                for Y1 = 5,-1,-1 do
                    for Z1 = 1, 5 do
                        temp[#temp + 1] = {X = X1, Y = Y1, Z = Z1}
                    end
                end
            end

            temp1[Line] = temp
        end

        temp2[block] = temp1
    end

    temp3[facedir] = temp2
end
```

For reference `tab = {key = value}` will create a table, store it in the `tab` variable with a key of `"key"` and a value of whatever is in the variable `value`. If you want to use a variable as the key you need to use the longer `tab = {[key] = value}` format for the key. The bare word version is simply syntactic sugar for `tab = {["key"] = value}`.

Comment: Well it does make the hierchy but no data, figured out that whole console lua thing, not as bad as i figured 

it outputs the hierchy but there is no data inside?

Comment: cthayn@TBCC-FBOI:~$ lua mylua.t
{{{{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, }, {{{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, }, {{{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, }, {{{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, }, }, }

Comment: after a manual formatting check that is correct just all the arrays are empty.

Comment: It definitely has contents here though I just noticed that the inner loop is still wrong if you want to accumulate various combinations of `X1`, `Y1` and `Z1`. Editing to fix that.

Comment: 379: 
    X: 5
    Z: 4
    Y: 0
   380: 
    X: 5
    Z: 5
    Y: 0
   381: 
    X: 5
    Z: 1
    Y: -1
   382: 
    X: 5
    Z: 2
    Y: -1
   383: 
    X: 5
    Z: 3
    Y: -1
   384: 
    X: 5
    Z: 4
    Y: -1
   385: 
    X: 5
    Z: 5
    Y: -1

Comment: stupid print function i had copy and pasted was garbage, replaced it and poof.... now i just have to figure out how to reset that 382 etc to the max each time which shouldnt be hard.

Comment: that is too F in clean!!! SERIOUSLY Thanks a million! hopefully in the next couple hours ill have a working mock up of the finished lua script and i can put a link here so you can see the full result, again thanks a million!

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment about 382 there. That 382 is the 382nd entry in the inner table because that's how many combinations of X/Y/Z values your loop creates.

Comment: ok using your print function right, the table looks like this:

Comment: added the table above. when i use the print command for tables that u gave me on the static tables they come out differently and i am working on trying to make the data match, so far the first one will match but then after that i have 13 data sets. the data needs to be generated in a way that is pattern consecutive. for the first dataset or facedir the x swings in an equal number of numerals from negative to positive then

Comment: y goes from a high positive integer to a negative integer, and z is constant until all sequential combinations of y and x are ehxausted, then is incremented by 1, the process is to repeat until the z stop point is reached. typeing all this i believe i have this assembledup side down, z should be the outer loop and x the inner